# How to update dict value in ansible inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a role test.

In roles/test/defaults/mail.yaml

```
# defaults file for test
data: 
  a: hello
```

How can I override the value of `data.a` from inventory file

I tried Below syntax in inventory file but didn't worked

1).

```
[master]
Master ansible_host=127.0.0.1 data.a=world
```

2)

```
[master]
Master ansible_host=127.0.0.1 data['a']=world
```

Is there any correct way to only override a specific key not the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't do what you're asking about, although there is a [specific configuration option you can set to change the default behavior](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). You can read about that in the linked docs, but I don't recommend enabling it, because that will make the behavior of your playbooks dependent on the ansible configuration wherever it happens to be running, which can cause surprises if either (a) you run the playbook on another machine and you forget to include the appropriate configuration or (b) if someone other than you runs the playbook.

In standard usage, if you have in `defaults/main.yml`:

```
data:
  a: something
  b: something else
```

You can override the `data` variable itself in your inventory, although if you want a structured variable like a dictionary you'll need to use the YAML inventory format:

```
all:
  children:
    master:
      hosts:
        Master:
          ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
          data:
            a: another thing
```

Using this inventory, the value of `data` would be `{"a": "another thing"}`.

You can work around this by using a different variable name for the default and the host-specific override.  E.g., if you have in `defaults/main.yml`:

```
data:
  a: foo
  b: bar
```

And in your inventory, or `host_vars`, or `group_vars` you have:

```
host_data:
  a: red
  c: bucket
```

Then you can use the `combine` filter when accessing the data:

```
{{ data|combine(host_data) }}
```

That would evaluate to a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
  "a": "red",
  "b": "bar",
  "c": "bucket"
}
```

In an example task:

```
- name: iterate over the keys and values of our variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} is {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ (data|combine(host_data))|dict2items }}"
```

Which given our sample data above would produce:

```
TASK [iterate over the keys and values of our variable] ***************************************
ok: [Master] => (item={'key': u'a', 'value': u'red'}) => {
    "msg": "a is red"
}
ok: [Master] => (item={'key': u'c', 'value': u'bucket'}) => {
    "msg": "c is bucket"
}
ok: [Master] => (item={'key': u'b', 'value': u'bar'}) => {
    "msg": "b is bar"
}
```